# Stack Exchange popup

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, notifications

The popup at the upper left corner titled "Stack Exchange", which gives a summary of the responses you get, does not work these days. It usually says that an error occured, and the list that is supposed to show comes blank. Can it be fixed?

Comment: I have not seen that behavior.  (I use Firefox 8 on Windows.)

Comment: It is likely that it may be related to the internet access problem, but even when the rest of the page is loaded, the popup often has problems, so I suspect the popup requires extra load.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the content of the inbox is loaded separately when you click the “StackExchange” logo.  Therefore, if there is a connection problem after the page is loaded, then the inbox may not be loaded even if the page is loaded.  If the connection problem is not on the server side, I do not think that this is a problem with the website.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto I see. I think you are right. Thanks.

Comment: I face the same problem, but it is difficult to pinpoint the cause. Usually it resolves itself after a few refreshes or restart of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have been due to some flakiness in our caching servers, which were very heavily loaded.

They have since been upgraded significantly; let us know if you still see this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems to be improved since.